# Java jackson embedded object deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have in response

```
{
   "item": {
     "field1": 1,
     "field2": 1,
   }
}
```

I want to deserialize it to `Privacy` class with 2 fields `field1` and `field2`.

A have added

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, unwrapRootValue);
```

But now I receive an exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Root name 'item' does not match expected ('Privacy') for type [simple type, class com.myproj.Privacy]
```

How can I map this class to json object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer: we have to add `@JsonRootName(value = "item")` annotation to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flexjson Deserialize
[Deserialize](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/javadoc/flexjson/JSONDeserializer.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is not a link-only answer. @i3arnon

Comment: @I3arnon Because the advice to "use Flexjson Deserialize" is, while not a *great* answer, an answer.

Comment: @chrylis A "link-only answer" doesn't mean it's not an answer. It means it doesn't add much value without the link, which is breakable. `"While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference"`

Comment: @chrylis `"would this answer still be useful without any internet connection?"` My answer would be no. Without the link this answer is barely a comment.

Comment: @I3arnon ,chrylis I only want suggest another way to deserialize the Object, you know