# Jackson Deserialization of Embedded Java Object

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have to deserialize following json using Jackson library into Customer class

```
{
   "code":"C001",
   "city": "Pune",
   "street": "ABC Road"
}
```

and Classes as

```
class Address{
    String city;
    String street;
}

class Customer{
    String code;
    Address address;
}
```

I have found similar question on stack 
[Java jackson embedded object deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564116/java-jackson-embedded-object-deserialization)

but answer does not apply to my case. Also I only want to use Jackson library.

How can I map this json to Customer object?

Comment: have u try `class Customer extends  Address` and then provide customer type in `objectmapper.getConstructType(Customer.Class)` Object. this may help you .. not tried but suggest u as per my experience.. Hope this may work..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put a [@JsonUnwrapped](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureUnwrapping) annotation on the `Address` field in the customer class. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonValue {
    final static String JSON = "{\n"
            +"   \"code\":\"C001\",\n"
            +"   \"city\": \"Pune\",\n"
            +"   \"street\": \"ABC Road\"\n"
            +"}";

    static class Address {
        public String city;
        public String street;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Address{" +
                    "city='" + city + '\'' +
                    ", street='" + street + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static class Customer {
        public String code;
        @JsonUnwrapped
        public Address address;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Customer{" +
                    "code='" + code + '\'' +
                    ", address=" + address +
                    '}';
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Customer.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 Customer{code='C001', address=Address{city='Pune', street='ABC Road'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a custom deserializer. [Jackson How-To: Custom Deserializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers)

For your use case it could be something like this:

```
class CustomerDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Customer>
{
  public Customer deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
                                        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
    String code = node.get("code").asText();
    String city = node.get("city").asText();
    String street = node.get("street").asText();
    Address adr = new Address(city, street);
    return new Customer(code, adr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object for a customer should look like this:

```
{
   "code":"C001",
   "address":{
        "city": "Pune",
        "street": "ABC Road"
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I have legacy code which gives me such json request.

Comment: Ok, in this case you should deserialize your JSON in a matching Java object and convert it within your Java code manually into the required object structure like suggested by  @Boris Pavlović

Answer (score 1):

Without some additional transformation this json structure can't be mapped to two classes. Either write a class `CustomerAddress` that will be having all three fields from json and then create `Address getAddress()` and `Customer getCustomer()` in it or transform the json to nest the address information inside the customer field as suggested by @eztam.

```
public CustomerAddress {
  private String code;
  private String city;
  private String street;

  public Address getAddress() {
    return new Address(city, street);
  }

  public Address getCustomer() {
    return new Customer(code, this.getAddress());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this !!!

```
{  
       "code":"customer1",
       "address":{  
          "type":"nested",
          "properties":{  
             "city":"Hyderabad",
             "street":"1000ftRoad"
          }
       }
    }
```